# Retrieve Billing Address from Stripe checkout session?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am creating a checkout session in Node like so.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

I've set the `billing_address_collection` parameter to `required` and am now wondering if I can retrieve the billing address collected from the `checkout.completed` webhook that is triggered.

I'm not finding a good way to retrieve the billing address from a checkout session.

Is there a way to do this? Or should I just gather this information before sending the user to a checkout session?

Answer (score 7):

Billing address can be collected via Checkout. It won't live on the CheckoutSession object though but instead on the PaymentMethod object.

When you get the `checkout.session.completed` event, it has a `payment_intent` field with the PaymentIntent object ID. The PaymentIntent object in turn has the PaymentMethod that you need. So you need to go from CheckoutSession -> PaymentIntent -> PaymentMethod to get the billing details.

How to do this: In your webhook event handler, retrieve [0] the PaymentIntent and `expand` the PaymentMethod (by passing `expand: ['payment_method']`).

The PaymentMethod has the billing details under the `billing_details` hash [2]

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve

[1]https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-billing_details

Comment:  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The payment_intent is null in my case. How are we supposed to get that ?

Comment: Tibo do you have more info? Are you creating a CheckoutSession and `payment_intent` is null there? What is the test mode CheckoutSession ID?

Comment: I'm looking at Webhooks - so maybe we are not on the same page. When I'm getting the Webhooks back from checkout.session.completed the payment_intent is "null". I'm trying to get the billing data collected from the customer during checkout to appear in his bills, because it's not the case by default (that makes no sense to me but it's how it is)

Comment: @Tibo same case here, do you found any issue ?

Answer (score 1):

To update the customer with the billing address during a checkout session, use

```js
{
    "billing_address_collection": "required",
    "customer_update": {
        "address": "auto",
        "name": "auto"
    }
}
```

When [creating the checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer_update).

Then stripe will update the customer object for you, and you don't need to do it yourself in a webhook.