# Stripe - How to get billing address information in Checkout.Session

Tags: c#, .net-core, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the billing address from Stripe Checkout from a Webhook call.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the information from the form in the yellow rectangle.

This is my Checkout configuration :

```
var options = new SessionCreateOptions()
                {
                    CustomerEmail = user.Email,
                    BillingAddressCollection = "required",
                    ShippingAddressCollection = new SessionShippingAddressCollectionOptions
                    {
                        AllowedCountries = new List<string>
                        {
                          "FR",
                        },
                    },
                    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>() {
                       result.Payment.Type
                    },
                    LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>{
                        new SessionLineItemOptions
                          {
                            PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
                            {
                              UnitAmountDecimal = result.Payment.Amount * 100,
                              Currency = result.Payment.Currency,
                              ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                              {
                                Name = _stringLocalizer.GetString("StripeProductLabel"),
                              },
                            },
                            Quantity = 1,
                        },
                    },
                    Mode = result.Payment.Mode,
                    SuccessUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}" + "/payment/complete",
                    CancelUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}" + "/payment/cancel",
                    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { Constants.StripeMetaDataOrderId, result.Id }
                    }
                };
```

and when I receive the session objet in the completed event : `session = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;`

I can't get the information because the paymentIntent object is null ( information from : [Retrieve Billing Address from Stripe checkout session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065880/retrieve-billing-address-from-stripe-checkout-session) ).

This is an important feature from Sripe because the application is a B2B application to help professionals to create orders for their B2C business. It will avoid making custom code from something that exits in Stripe API :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked to is the correct way to get this information, from the `payment_method` on the `payment_intent`. I'm not sure how/why your `payment_intent` value would not be populated, as my testing indicates this to be initialized upon creating the session, even if I never redirect to it.

Are you certain you're creating a `mode=payment` session? I see that in the code you shared, but things will change a bit if you're actually doing `setup` or `subscription` mode.

Comment: Yep I'm in payment mode (It come from domain logic, it's why is not explicit here). After looking with functionnal team we decide to make Billing information in our system but thanks to confirm that my conf seems to be correct :)